# Update metadata

Tags: fiware-orion

In the documentation there is: [at the moment NGSIv2 doesn't define an operation to update metadata](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/user/metadata.md).
Any plan to add this feature?
At the moment, to update a metadata it seems that I need to update the whole attribute. So I need to read the whole attribute first and then update it. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct at the present moment (October 2017): there isn't any operation in the NGSIv2 API to manage metadata in the NGSIv2 API as individual resources (as entities, attributes or subscriptions are).

And yes, there are plans to include this functionality in the future :). Have a look to [this issue at Orion repository](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2567) for more details on it.